# Get list of all google sheets using gspread?

Tags: python, api, google-sheets, google-api, gspread

Currently I can connect using gspread and create/share a spreadsheet. I can also read data from said spreadsheet but I have to request it by name. Is there a way to list of all spreadsheets shared with the OAuth account being used.

I may not know all the names of the spreadsheets that will be shared with the account so I want to have them listed off programmatically if possible.

All I have been able to do so far is select a sheet by name. But I need to be able to pull a list of all sheets shared with my `service_account`.

Everything I have found so far online is related to getting a list of sheets in a workbook but not a list of all workbooks available.

Documentation is welcome though all the stuff I have found so far has not helped.

```
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
import tkinter as tk


class Main(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.geometry('1000x400')
        self.txt = tk.Text(self)
        self.txt.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')
        self.scope = ["https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds", 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',
                      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"]
        self.txt.insert('end', '{}\n'.format(self.scope))
        print('Scope: ', self.scope)
        self.after(2000, self.testing)

    def testing(self):
        creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('creds.json', self.scope)
        client = gspread.authorize(creds)

        try:
            sh = client.create('Created By App')
            sh.share('my.account@workemail.com', perm_type='user', role='writer')

        except Exception as e:
            print('Error: ', e)

        try:
            print('Client: ', client)
            try:
                self.txt.insert('end', '{}\n'.format('Running: client.list_permissions("TestingSheet")'))
                self.txt.insert('end', '{}\n\n'.format(client.list_permissions("TestingSheet")))
            except Exception as e:
                self.txt.insert('end', 'Error: {}\n\n'.format(e))
                print('Error: ', e)
            try:
                self.txt.insert('end', '{}\n'.format('Running: client.list_spreadsheet_files()'))
                self.txt.insert('end', '{}\n\n'.format(client.list_spreadsheet_files()))
            except Exception as e:
                self.txt.insert('end', 'Error: {}\n\n'.format(e))
                print('Error: ', e)
            try:
                self.txt.insert('end', '{}\n'.format('Running: client.session()'))
                self.txt.insert('end', '{}\n\n'.format(client.session()))
            except Exception as e:
                self.txt.insert('end', 'Error: {}\n\n'.format(e))
                print('Error: ', e)

            # Find a workbook by name and open the first sheet
            # Make sure you use the right name here.
            sheet = client.open("TestingSheet").sheet1
            self.txt.insert('end', '{}\n\n'.format(sheet))
            print('Sheet: ', sheet)
            # Extract and print all of the values
            list_of_hashes = sheet.get_all_records()
            self.txt.insert('end', '{}\n\n'.format(list_of_hashes))
            print('list_of_hashes: ', list_of_hashes)
        except Exception as e:
            self.txt.insert('end', 'Error: {}\n\n'.format(e))
            print('Error: ', e)
```

creds.json is formated like this:

```
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "private_key_id": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "client_email": "project-service-account@XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "client_id": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/project-service-account@XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.iam.gserviceaccount.com"}
```

Answer (score 3):

It is possible.

```py
import gspread
gc = gspread.service_account('./creds.json')
def createNewSheetIfNotExist(title):
    if title not in [sh.title for sh in gc.openall()]:
        gc.create(title)
    print([sh.title for sh in gc.openall()])
    
createNewSheetIfNotExist('Test')
createNewSheetIfNotExist('Test')
```

Running the function multiple times will not add a new sheet because it has found its title inside `gc.openall()`.

[gspread API Reference](https://docs.gspread.org/en/v4.0.1/api.html?highlight=openall#gspread.Client.openall)

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to list all shared Google Sheets file using [Gspread](https://docs.gspread.org/en/latest/index.html#gspread). Since it uses [Google Sheets API v4](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts), there is no existing method in Sheets API to list Google Sheets files in your drive.

You need to use [Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-sdk?hl=en) to search for Google Sheets file shared to your service account using [files.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list) with a query string `q="mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet' and sharedWithMe"`

Your [files.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list) request will return a list of [files](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files#resource) which contains the name of the file and its file id. Then you can use gspread to read/modify your Google Sheets file.

### Sample Response using API Explorer:

```
{
 "kind": "drive#fileList",
 "incompleteSearch": false,
 "files": [
  {
   "kind": "drive#file",
   "id": "1wXCD1SaujjD46NM7NFpP8jrqL_xxxxx",
   "name": "File1",
   "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet"
  },
  {
   "kind": "drive#file",
   "id": "1Bm7bFs8SveQt75geOGjDAmOgfxxxxx",
   "name": "File2",
   "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet"
  }]
}
```

You can check the following references on how to setup and use Drive API in Python:

- [Python Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python?hl=en)
- [Search for specific files or folders on the current user's My Drive - Sample Python script included](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/search-files?hl=en#search_for_specific_files_or_folders_on_the_current_users_my_drive)

Comment: Thank you. This sounds promising. I will have to test this when I get a chance. I will update with an accepted answer once I have confirmed.

Answer (score 1):

If the goal is to obtain a list of workbook names, the following works:

```py
import gspread

gc = gspread.service_account("./creds.json")
workbooks = [file["name"] for file in gc.list_all_spreadsheets()]
```

The `.list_all_spreadsheets` method of the `gc` instance of gspread's `Client` object returns a list of dictionaries with the information of every spreadsheet shared with the `service account`.

If our service account had been shared to from 3 different spreadsheets, "Workbook 1", "Workbook 2", and "Workbook 3", then this method would return the following.

```py
[{'kind': 'drive#file',
  'id': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  'name': 'Workbook 1',
  'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet'},
 {'kind': 'drive#file',
  'id': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  'name': 'Workbook 2',
  'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet'},
 {'kind': 'drive#file',
  'id': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  'name': 'Workbook 3',
  'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet'}]
```

I decided to use list comprehension to loop through these dictionaries. Feel free to go about this step in another manner. If the above is the result of `gc.list_all_spreadsheets()`, then `workbooks` would be

```py
['Workbook 1', 'Workbook 2', 'Workbook 3']
```